# Capture only the file path from the file upload control

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update some local access databases from a web database. When I am accessing the web page, I want the user to select a folder on the local hard drive where the DB's reside that will be updated by the program. I actually have been using the File Upload control to do this as it has allowed me to check the file extensions on the local DB's their file size and other misc. items.

This captures the full path with the file name...

```
fileName = FileUploadAccess.PostedFile.FileName.ToLower
```

Now I have a need to capture the full path of the db's on the local hard drive. I can get the full path with the filename, but then I need to write a bunch of code to strip the filename from the path variable.

Is there a simple way to capture the path of the location the DB when the file location is selected, something like this....

```
Dim thePath As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: FileUpload-Control does not allow to access the full path of the uploaded file because a webserver shouldn't be interested in the client's file-system. This was only possible until IE6: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx

Comment: But there are properties that you can use to acquire the local path in VB processing. As I stated this is not a server side need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IO.Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx#Y0)

Here is a sample code:

```
Dim MyDirectoryPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(MyFullPath)
```

Comment: awesome @Mahdi, worked great. I'll be able to use this in the rest of the code. Thanks again.